# I would not be able to get my simulation in my life time

Tags: time-complexity, computability, runtime-analysis, polynomial-time, polynomial-time-reductions

I am running a simulation on my computer. I tried to multiply two polynomials $g(x), h(x)\in GF(2)[x]$, with $degree(g(x))= 8165$, and $degree(h(x))=25$. This multiplication took almost $20$ minutes on my computer.

Now, I have to multiply all $h(x)\in GF(2)[x]$ of $degree(h(x))\leq 25$ with $g(x)$. I estimated that it would take $2553.6$ years to complete the job. So, I would not be able to get my result in my lifetime. So, I am looking for your suggestion. Can a supercomputer finish this job in 1-4 weeks?

Comment: 20 minutes seems way too much, GF[2] arithmetic is so simple ! What did you use ?

Comment: By the way, what is the use of computing those 67108864 polynomials ?

Comment: With well optimized software using bit packing, I would expect below two hours of work. Maybe less with AVX vectorization.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ; I am using BitVector (in python) for the computation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ; What kind of software would you propose?

Comment: Even Python should be much faster than that, they use bit packing !? I would code this in C.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ; Are you suggesting that if I code this in C, I would be able to get my result in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: I can't believe that it took 20 minutes. Did you use gf_multiply_modular() ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust ; I used fg= gf_multiply() for multiplication. Why dont you believe me?

Comment: Because a quick estimate of the operation count shows that there is a problem... Possibly intense (but useless) memory allocation ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust ; I would give you my code if you want to verify the execution time. Please share your email i.d.

Comment: I made a few tests. This software is dead slow. The behavior should be linear in the size of the long polynomial, but it is not at all.  Drop it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust; Are you suggesting I drop my idea to get my simulation result?

Comment: Grrrr, wasn't I clear enough that this software is bad ? Your whole computation can be performed in an hour.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for the software?

Comment: I already answered.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ; Then I would have to code in C?

Comment: Why not, that's an option.

Comment: Please don't put information/clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question so it contains all information needed to answer it, reads well for someone who encounters this post for the first time, and is self-contained.  Then you can flag comments as 'no longer needed'. Thank you!

Comment: @RobinKurtz Can you share your Python code as well as a few examples online somewhere?